# Custom Swipe Listview Android

Tags: android, listview, swipe

Currently I am working on SwipeListView.

Two libraries I have found is :

https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview
and

https://github.com/dharanikumar/IOS_7-SwipeGesture-Android

Both are best for normal Usage.
The requirement for me is to keep row background transparent.

Due to this the background button shows up.

So is there any another library available which

> GENERATES MENU ABOVE THE LIST ITEM

or

> THERE IS ANY POSSIBILITIES OF CHANGING THE LIBRARY CODE FOR GETTING REQUIRED RESULTS.

Hope I any get some workaround from you.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.desarrollodroide.repos&hl=en check this out. there are lots custom listviews

Comment: @QadirHussain I have this library app. from many months, I have found this from this app. only.